# Does a foreign key reduce redundancy if all the columns are referenced?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, normalization

I've read that one of the benefits of normalization is to reduce redundancy in the DB. But I'm wondering, if you end up referencing all the columns in the target table?

For example, if I have a Video table that references a Genre table, the Genre table might very likely have a single column with a dozen fairly static values like 'Horror' 'Sci-Fi' 'Romance' etc.

In a case like this, does it save any space to separate the two, or is the only benefit making it so you can update all referencing rows from one place?

Comment: Replacing values by other values that are ids plus an old-to-new lookup table is not normalization. Normalization to 1NF rearranges a table to remove nested values for simplifying queries & normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by projections of it to avoid recording the same thing more than once in an uncontrolled way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, space saving is **ONE** of the benefits, not the only one.

In the case you mentioned, no, you'll save no space if you use that one column as the PK which is fine.

You could abstract that table with a autonumber/sequence and use that as the PK, and make the current column the candidate key (so it stays unique).

But leaving your design exactly as you've outlined, the benefit is in consistency. You'll have only those 12 values... you'll not accidentally enter a value for "Horrer" or "PSY-Fi"

Comment: A lot of good answers. Thanks everyone! Poor Joe Celko would be mortified at all the surrogate groupies here :D You get my vote, Stephanie, because you read my question carefully and responded quickly and clearly.

Comment: Thanks. I think programmer-type people take rules to extremes... always do x and that means forever and ever amen. But I think that you need to understand why people say to always do x because then you'll know the cases why not.

Answer (score 2):

Saving space is one benefit to separating the 2 tables.  Like it was said before, putting a Genre_ID in place of an actual value such as "Horror" or "Adventure" will save space.

In my opinion, the better part of doing this to to enforce integrity.  If you put in the text values in the Video table, what prevents you from changing the value accidentally?  Now some rows may have "Adventure" or "Action/Adventure" and so on.  By having 2 tables and referencing with a foreign key, you're going to have better control over what values can be a genre.

In summary, don't worry about the fact that you reference all the columns, especially if a table has very few columns.  If you decide to add an ID field, or just keep the 1 column table as a list of "acceptable values", your goal should be to enforce integrity first, and save space or I/O costs second.

Comment: I wish I could vote your answer 2nd. You answered sooner, but Stephanie's was a bit clearer and to the point--I knew right away that no, in the case I described, the FK would not save space.

Comment: Stephanie's answer is indeed clearer and quicker to the point.  This is what I get from reading textbooks all the time!

Answer (score 0):

I would use surrogate keys (Autonumber, Identity, etc) and use that for the foreign key join instead of the actual value.

The idea is more about data quality than reducing space.

In most db's an INT will be smaller than Varchar2 (20)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will save space if you have a surrogate key (int) which you use in the video table instead of the varchar(20) or whatever the genra would be.

Answer (score 0):

But you've hit the problem yourself there:

> single column with a dozen fairly
>   static values like 'Horror' 'Sci-Fi'
>   'Romance' etc.

With surrogate keys and normalized tables, you only have "Horror" stored once in database, but its ID number is stored in several places (a simple number is smaller than the text most of the time, and does save space).  Not only does it increase the maintainability of the database, but it does indeed save raw space.

Comment: He was using the values as the PK. He said referencing ALL the columns... and in this case the ONLY column.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you want to ensure that your rows in the Video table have valid/predetermined entries for Genre? If you don't have a foreign key constraint you would need an enum for that column in the Video table and then you would have to change the schema every time you add a new Genre instead of just adding a new row to a Genre table.

Comment: I never knew enum was a SQL construct. Which ANSI SQL Standard is that in?

Comment: I don't think it is perse: but an enum would be a way of not having a foreign key and constraining the values.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like that, your key values plus their indexes can be considerably larger than the data itself.  Another model of doing simple codes like that is to have a table of codes and then an insert and update check constraint to validate them.  That also avoids a join in order to get the genre data out.  Which way you do it is kind of a toss up and would depend on what your application queries tend to be.

Answer (score 0):

[Data modification anomalies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies)

- What if you add a new genre?
- Is Sci-Fi the same as SciFi?
- Is Sci-Fi the same as Sci-fi?

It gets worse if you another table, say, "Books" that have the same Genres.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization has nothing to do with saving space. It's about eliminating potential anomalies that can occur as a result of certain kinds of redundancy. Since normalization defines the logical level only it would be quite possible for a normalized database to be physically larger or physically smaller than a denormalized or un-normalized one.

It is true that normalization generally makes designs that ought to translate efficiently into storage - but that's really down to the features of the DBMS rather than something implicit in normalization.

Answer (score -1):

You will save also because 'Horror' takes 12 bytes in Unicode, while GenreId can be a Byte or char(1).

Comment: Byte? Char? What happens when a lookup goes beyond 255 values?

Comment: @Raj More: then you use an integer or whatsoever, but anyway there's a benefit. Could you find that yourself ?